# How to summarize SQL table to return value conditionally

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a table with several rows, and several columns. It looks like this:

```
Name    Description
X         PASS
X         PASS
X         FAIL
```

I want it to return only one row. If all of them are PASS, return PASS.
If one or more of them are FAIL, then return FAIL.

What's the best way to go about achieving this in SQL Server 2008?

EDIT: The values in the name column will always be the same.

Comment: I think you should edit your subject to be more clear.

Comment: I did sort of struggle with the name...can you suggest a better one?

Comment: Perhaps How to summarize table to return proper PASS/FAIL value

Comment: What if there are no rows, what would you want it to return?

Comment: Can there be more than one name?

Comment: Can the description field ever contain `NULL` ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Depending on the database indexes, and assuming you want one row returned per unique name, I would look at the performance of

```
select 
  name, 
  min([description]) as description
from 
    tableA
group by
name
```

compared to the other solutions

Comment: You don't know if there can be multiple names... in which case this would return more than one row.

Comment: Yes, I am assuming he wants one row per name. I'll edit my answer.

Comment: His assumption was correct, I will edit my questin to be more clear

Answer (score 3):

```
SELECT TOP 1 CASE Description WHEN 'FAIL' THEN 'FAIL' ELSE 'PASS' END
FROM DaTable
ORDER BY Description
```

OP: Is it possible that the table is empty? In that case this query won't return any rows, obviously.

**EDIT**

According to aquinas's comment I created a modified query without ordering:

```
SELECT CASE COUNT(Description) WHEN 0 THEN 'FAIL' ELSE 'PASS' END
FROM DaTable
WHERE Description = 'FAIL'
```

This query will return PASS if DaTable is empty.

Comment: This may be simple, but is it going to have to sort the table first to get the one row? I would think exist would be better because it can stop scanning as soon as it finds a row that satisfies the query. Could be wrong though

Comment: @aquinas Thanks for your comment. I edited my answer with an orderby free alternative.

Answer (score 2):

This is the simplest solution you will find:

```
SELECT MIN(Description) FROM tbl
```

If there's at least one `FAIL`, then our `result` column will contain `FAIL`, otherwise, it will contain `PASS`.

Comment: +1 nice one. Important to note that it won't return results if the table is empty.

Comment: @daniloquio, thanks =). The OP stated that there will always be rows. The `MIN()` will return `NULL` if the table is empty. See what I did in my past edits to account for this before the OP edited the question.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `EXISTS` to get the existance of a row containing "FAIL".

You could also try something like:

```
SELECT TOP 1 COALESCE(tFail.Description,t.Description)
FROM myTable AS t
LEFT JOIN myTable AS tFail ON tFail.Name = t.Name AND tFail.Description = 'FAIL' 
WHERE t.Name = 'x'
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is the query:

```
--DROP TABLE result
CREATE TABLE result(Name varchar(10),Description varchar(20))
--select * from result 
INSERT INTO result 
VALUES('X','PASS'),('X','PASS'),('X','FAIL')

;WITH CTE(descp,cnt) as (SELECT  [description],COUNT(*)  as cnt FROM result group by [description])
SELECT CASE WHEN COUNT(*) > 1 then 'FAIL'  when COUNT(*)=1  then MAX(descp) else 'PASS' END FROM CTE
```